# Create recursive SQL statement that calculates total number of quantities

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, oracle11g, recursive-query

I am not able to find the solution for my problem. I have 4 tables:

**BomModule:** This table represents a module in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE "BOMMODULE"
(
    "MODULEID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ISROOTMODULE"     NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "MODULENAME"       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    ...
)
```

**BomItem:** This table represents a leaf - or an item in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE "BOMITEM"
(
    "ITEMID"     NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    ...
)
```

**ModuleConnection:** This table maps a module to another parent module. You can define the quantity of submodules that belong to a specific parent module.

```
CREATE TABLE "MODULECONNECTION"
(
    "ID"       NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "QUANTITY"   NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SUBMODULE_MODULEID"   NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PARENTMODULE_MODULEID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    ...
)
```

**ItemModuleConnection:**
This table maps all leave-items to a module. Furthermore, you can define the quantity of items for one module.

```
CREATE TABLE "ITEMMODULECONNECTION"
(
    "ID"       NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ITEMID"   NUMBER(10,0),
    "MODULEID" NUMBER(10,0),
    ...
)
```

As you can see from the table structure, items and modules are connected to each other and have different quantities. Due to the fact that those connections are very flexible, I am not able to create a SQL statement, that will provide me the total quantity for an item:

```
select quantity from ...... where itemId = xy;
```

The SQL statement should check all quantities from the item to the root module and multiply them:

```
2 x rootmodule (total 2)
-- 1x submodule 1 (total 2)
-- 2x submodule 2 (total 4)
---- 5x item 1 (total 20)
---- 6x item 2 (total 24)
```

Please help me create this sql statement, much appreciate your answer!

Constraints:
 
- It has to be a SQL statement (It is used in a Java application)
- Database is Oracle 11g

Comment: I tried it directly with Java (Collections), but that uses a lot of ressources. Unfortunately I don't know how to use recursion in SQL.

Comment: There's a cut'n'paste error in the tables you posted.  I have tried to fix it but I'm not sure it's right.  Please check

Comment: How recursive is this?  Can Sub-modules act as parents to other modules?  Also, can you guarantee the integrity of the connections? Loops (PM->SM1, SM1->SM2, SM2->PM) are a PITN.  So are multiple paths (PM1->SM1, PM2->SM1) or short-circuits (PM->SM1, SM1->SM2, PM->SM2).

Comment: How are the quantities of the modules determined? It seems that the quantity is an attribute of the connection rather than the module. In the example you have shown, I don't see how it's possible for there to be two "root modules" and one "submodule 1". Am I missing something here?

Comment: @APC, yes submodules can act as parents, the integrity is guaranteed by the program logic, it is not possible to add loops (but of course, on database level it would be possible).

Comment: @Mike Meyers, the quantities are attributes of the ManyToMany table. A module can be defined as root module and has different submodules or items.

Comment: Once more question.  Which version of Oracle 11g: R1 or R2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using Java, instead of SQL. This is my approach:

```
/**
 * This recursive functions interates through the whole tree and checks if there are items and modules.
 * As soon as an item is found, it is multiplied with the module amount. The result is saved in a HashMap. 
 * This HashMap is being parsed in the end.
 */
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> updateBom(HashMap<Integer, Integer> bom, BomModule module, int amount, BomHandling bh) {
    if(bom == null) {
        bom = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }
    // get all items for this parent module
    Collection<ItemModuleConnection> items = bh.getItems(module.getModuleId());
    Iterator<ItemModuleConnection> itemIterator = items.iterator();

    while(itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        ItemModuleConnection con = itemIterator.next();

        int itemQuantity = con.getQuantity() * amount;

        // if bom item already exists in bom list, get it and update quantity
        Integer currentItemQuantity = new Integer(0);
        if(bom.containsKey(new Integer(con.getItem().getItemId()))) {
            currentItemQuantity = bom.get(con.getItem().getItemId());
            bom.remove(bom.get(con.getItem().getItemId()));
        }
        bom.put(con.getItem().getItemId(), currentItemQuantity + itemQuantity);
    }

    // get all modules for this parent module
    Collection<ModuleConnection> modules = bh.getConnections(module.getModuleId());
    Iterator<ModuleConnection> moduleIterator = modules.iterator();

    // set the quantity of the module by multiplying it with the amount
    while(moduleIterator.hasNext()) {
        ModuleConnection moduleCon = moduleIterator.next();
        int moduleQuantity = moduleCon.getQuantity();
        updateBom(bom, moduleCon.getSubModule(), moduleQuantity * amount, bh);
    }
    return bom;
}
```

Before I print the single Items, I call this updateBom()-function and then retrieve the values from the HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> bom = updateBom(null, bomModule, 1, bh);
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = bom.entrySet().iterator();

while (entries.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> bomEntry = entries.next();
    BomItem item = bh.getBomItem(bomEntry.getKey());
    Integer itemAmount = bomEntry.getValue();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `connect by` and `start with` clauses of oracle. Sorry don't have time to actually come up with a sql statement, but the syntax is explained here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html